# How can I send new line feed in a POST call using plain text in JavaScript ES6 / Prometheus

Tags: javascript, http, post, ecmascript-6, prometheus

I am trying to send a payload using POST to a Prometheus gateway server.

This server expects the request to be text/plain and it must end with a new line feed character.

*"Using the Prometheus text protocol, pushing metrics is so easy that no separate CLI is provided. Simply use a command-line HTTP tool like curl. Your favorite scripting language has most likely some built-in HTTP capabilities you can leverage here as well.
Note that in the text protocol, each line has to end with a line-feed character (aka 'LF' or '\n'). Ending a line in other ways, e.g. with 'CR' aka '\r', 'CRLF' aka '\r\n', or just the end of the packet, will result in a protocol error."*

```
var payload = 'http_requests_total{method="post", code="200"} 1000 1295000000000'

var apiRequest = http.request{{
  'endpoint': 'http//myserver/api/metrics',
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': {
  'content-type': 'text/plain',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'UTF-8'
   }
)}
var resp = apiRequest.write(payload);
```

If I send as is, I receive a 400 response saying "unexpected end of input stream"

This is because the payload does not end with a line feed character.

I have tried to add "\n" but this doesn't work.

```
var payload = 'http_requests_total{method="post", code="200"} 1000 1295000000000' + '\n'
```

Am I missing something fundamental? If I send a curl request is works! but I am limited to using JavaScript ES6.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the payload from the network tab in your browser's dev tools and send it using curl? Does it work? You could use a packet sniffer like WireShark to compare the requests from your browser and from curl.

Comment: `+ '\n'` should have worked. You can also just put `\n` at the end of the payload string without `+`, e.g. `1295000000000\n'`. I can't see any reason why this isn't working, it's exactly what they said.

Comment: The strange thing is that `curl` doesn't normally add a newline, so when they say that you can just use `curl`, it probably won't work.

Comment: You're missing `})` at the end of the call to `http.request`

Comment: Fixed that Barmar thank you, typo. 

Yes I agree it is strange, I have tried through postman with just `\n` and `"\n"` using raw text but its just passing it through as plain text. 

If I manually enter a new line (so two lines) and then add a pre-req script 

`pm.request.body.update(pm.request.body.raw.replace(/(\r)/gm, ''))`

I can get it to work in postman. When I inspect the logs the only difference I see if postman adds a ↲ after my payload